# Get a specific field from a xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to loop through an xml file and check all the email fields to see if they match a predefined email and if it does grab the `contactid`

The issue I am having is the structure of the xml file doesnt seem to be put together in a way that makes looping through it easy.

For example I am using this snippet to parse the xml file

```php
$p = xml_parser_create();
            xml_parse_into_struct($p,$response,$vals,$index);
            xml_parser_free($p);

            echo "\nVals array\n";

            print_r($vals);
?>
```

Using this I can get the `contactid` of the first row by doing `$vals[4]` but the structure of the file does not let me loop to check other fields that I can think of.

I have tried other methods of parsing the xml file but they all seem to look the same as the one in the link below

This is the xml file that `$response` returns http://deathcrow.altervista.org/response.xml

How can I loop over all the emails in the xml file and cross reference them and then grab the `contactid` of the one that matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SimpleXML and XPath can make this 'easier'.  The XPath is the main part which will allow you to find the data your after...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://deathcrow.altervista.org/response.xml");

// Test email to find
$email = 'lyounger42@gamil.com';   
$contactID = $xml->xpath("//row[FL[@val='Email'][text()='$email']]/FL[@val='CONTACTID']");

echo (string)$contactID[0];
```

outputs

```
2594788000014076002
```

To break down the XPath...

```
//row[FL[@val='Email'][text()='$email']]/FL[@val='CONTACTID']
```

This looks for a row element with the attribute val (`@val`) for the Email and then checks the value (`text()`) is the email address your after.

The final

```
/FL[@val='CONTACTID']
```

picks out the FL element for the contactID.

As XPath will return a list of matches, the last line uses `$contactID[0]` to just return the first match.  Using `(string)` ensures that it will be a string rather than a SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: This works for a file on my server but does not work in the case that `$response` is an xml response from an api call which in this case results in the error "Fatal Error: call to a member function xpath() on boolean"

Comment: If you already have the response as a string - change the first line to `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response)`.